# How can we align two different item in the text-box

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 and I have textbox which returns the amount . I am rendering the report in excel. Right now I can get $ symbol on the report. But Client needs the "$" currency to be left justified and amount to be right justified when rendered in to the excel. How can I do in .rdlc format Something like this |$       2000| . How Can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the rectangle and inside it place two text box one with $ and other with amount and align each text-box to left and right respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both your expression (one to determine the currentcy symbol, one to dispalky the amount int he sam etext both.

1. Create a new textbox, and right-click, select `Expression...`
2. Create your symbol expression
3. Right click the **same** textbox and choose `Create Placeholder...`
4. Create your amount expression
5. Results in a design like this

   [image]

Alternatively, you could set a Custom Format for the textbox, like

```
'$'0.00;('$'0.00)
```

That sets the $ sign to the left of the amount, like so

[image]

Comment: they wanted like this  |$  - - - - - 30000| - - = Space

Comment: Also I tried adding space in the expression provided but that shrinks or expands based on number of digits .